# Trying to install Linux Mint 13 via Wubi, throws me into grub prompt

Tags: linux-mint, grub, system-installation, wubi

I'm trying to install Linux Mint 13 with Cinnamon via the 64 bit DVD image from within Windows. I've tried both installing it to `C:` which is my Windows system disk, but also to `D:` which is another physical disk entirely. The same thing happens on both disks.

The Windows part of the installation completes and it tells me to reboot. When I reboot, it tries rebooting into Linux Mint to start the installation, but I only get a prompt saying `grub >`. If I try the `boot` command, it says no kernel is loaded.

I've tried looking at the boot record in EasyBCD, and it looks like this:

```
Entry #1
Name: Windows 7
BCD ID: {current}
Drive: C:\
Bootloader Path: \Windows\system32\winload.exe

Entry #2
Name: Linux Mint
BCD ID: {62256248-e57d-11e1-9eca-d50aae34d088}
Drive: C:\
Bootloader Path: \linuxmint\winboot\wubildr.mbr
```

Booting Windows 7 works fine obviously, but I'm not sure why Linux Mint fails. The Bootloader Path for the Linux Mint installation checks out.

Any ideas why this is happening, and/or what I can do to troubleshoot it? I really want to install this via Wubi, and not have to mess around with partitions.

Answer (score 2):

I had a quick look around and it appears that there is a bug in GRUB2 that causes it to have problems booting from NTFS partitions ([source](http://www.omaregan.com/?p=608)):

> It seems the newer kernels (2.6.31-19 and up) and Grub2 had a strange
>   incompatibility when trying to boot from NTFS. In this write-up, they
>   mention that the cause of the problem is:
>
> > To be able to boot Wubi, Grub2 has to access the ntfs partition which
> >     is hosting Wubi. There is a bug in Grub 2, which prevents Grub2 to
> >     read any files on an ntfs partition beyond the first 4GB. If any of
> >     the boot files is outside of the 4GB limit, booting will fail.
> >     Depending on which boot file is outside the limit, the symptoms can be
> >     quite different. Since any kernel or Grub update relocates some of the
> >     boot files, you might be hit by this bug at any time.
>
> So, how do we fix this? It’s actually very easy. All you need to do is
>   download a new Wubildr file which corrects the problem [from here](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/36920146/wubildr). (You
>   can safely do this from within Windows if you cannot boot into Linux).
>   Then just copy that file to your Windows c:\ drive, overwriting the
>   faulty wubildr file that was there.

I have not tried it myself as I do not use wubi but it seems to work. Good luck.

[This](http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.ca/2011/08/missing-rootdisk.html) may also be helpful.

Comment: It now says "GRUB 1.99" on startup but I still go straight to the grub prompt. I replaced both the wubildr in the root of the C drive, and in the subfolder of the linuxmint folder.